# I'am getting a strange error while a the code in the tutorial works fine?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working on a project and I got a strange error on my code in line 18 while the dude on YouTube isn't getting an error. Can anyone help me with this error?

Here is the link to the Youtube Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UCWfdW6hcVA&t=1148s

[image: Code]
[image: Workbook]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line 18, the syntax

`` `E${lastRow}` ``

represents a [Javascript template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), where `${lastRow}` will be replaced with the value of `lastRow` (presumably an integer so you get a cell reference like `E3`).

Template literals should be delimited by backticks (`` ` ``), *not* single quotes (`'`).  Try replacing the single quotes with backticks.